# Sonar Runner doesn't execute PHPUnit

Tags: php, phpunit, sonarqube

I'm very new to Sonar, so I might be skipping something obvious :-/.

My problem is: I configured Sonar nearly correctly, many things work but not PHPUnit.

I installed the PHP Plugin but when I run `sonar-runner -e or -X`, PHP CodeSniffer is run, PHP Mess Detector is run, ..., but not PHPUnit.

Project settings like `sonar.phpUnit.skip` are the default ones (meaning it's configured to run).

There is nothing related to PHPUnit in my `sonar-project.properties` file in my project root folder.

- I've tried to move my `phpunit.xml.dist` file (while adapting file-paths to test files) around because at first it was in a subfolder of my project but it didn't work either.
- I've tried restarting the server multiple times.
- I've tried switching off and on again the options to make PHP MD, PHP CodeSniffer run or not run (it works for these).

PHPUnit works on the box'es command-line with the command named
`phpunit` and also with using it's switches like `phpunit -c path/to/my/phpunit.xml.dist`/ *`folder`*

Comment: Did you make the project sample work: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/projects/languages/php/php-sonar-runner-unit-tests ? As PHPUnit works manually, can you also give a try to the reuse report mode: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/PHP+Plugin ("Reusing existing reports" section) ?

Comment: How can you say it does not run? Which concrete feedback are you getting back? Which concrete feedback did you expect? Are you logging errors? If so, which errors do you get? Are you do verbose and/or debug logging? If not, please enable. Show the log for the concrete part related to your specific question. Tell us what you expected for verbose/debugging. Tell us what you get instead. Tell us about what you wonder in concrete. E.g. I can as well install phpunit on my machine and in some other application that also can use it, configure it that way that "it does not work". No surprises here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem after upgrading to sonar 3.7 and it seems to be fixed when I explicitly define the test source directories in sonar-project.properties :

```
sonar.tests=src/path/to/test
```

The runner logs will show something like this :

```
23:02:59.370 INFO  - Sensor PHPUnit Sensor...
```

This works as well when sonar is in "analyze only" mode and reading existing test and coverage report files.